# How to make a value not able to go below 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

[My javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVz7H.png*%5C)

okay so I'm trying to make a clicker idle game and I got the upgrade to take 100 from the current amount of points, but I can't seem to get it to not upgrade when the point count is above the required amount (in this case 100). I would like to add more upgrades in the future so I'd really love to receive some help since I couldn't find anything of use anywhere else. Thanks a lot in advance.

[The game when opened as a website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rza32.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Please, no scrrenshots of code, copy it and paste into question

Comment: `... value = Math.max(0, value); ...`

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is syntax, line 9

Your code:

```js
if (true) {clicks>100
```

In javascript the syntax of an if statement should be:

```js
if(<condition>) {
    <code to execute if condition is true>
}
```

To clarify, the full working code should look like:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

function removeClick() {
    if(clicks>100) {
        clicks -= 100;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LukeAlber-Kint Perhaps it's because your version is testing if the string "clicks" is greater than 100 instead of comparing the variable `clicks` with the 100. Don't forget to accept this answer if you get it working :)